# Create a tag for The Beyond

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I am a noob and I just asked a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92459/the-beyond-whyd-they-do-that) for the movie [The Beyond](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5723416)

Can/Should someone create a tag for the movie?